# events in angular not binding to vm

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular and cant seem to figure this out.

In my controller I am using the `var vm = this` syntax rather than using `$scope` but when trying to attach an `$on` event handler I get a `vm.$on` is not a function error.

This works:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
     console.log(vm.myform);
});
```

This does not:

```
var vm = this;

vm.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
     console.log(vm.myform);
});
```

could some please explain why.

Thanks
James

Comment: That is great, thank you very @MichaelRadionov much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

$on is a method of $rootscope ,you cannot access elsewhere.In angular js,event communication happens through $rootscope.broadcast and $rootscope.emit,to subscribe that event only we can use $rootscope.$on .To know more detail about this you can read

http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: Hey @vignesh thanks for pointing me to this article. I will take a look.